# How to read a specific number of bytes from a stream?

Tags: rust

I have a struct with a `BufStream<T>` where `T: Read+Write`.
The `BufStream` can be a `TcpStream` and I'd like to read n bytes from it.
Not a fixed amount of bytes in a predefined buffer, but I have a string/stream which indicates the number of bytes to read next.

Is there a nice way to do that?

Answer (score 35):

Since Rust 1.6, [`Read::read_exact`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_exact) can be used to do this. If `bytes_to_read` is the number of bytes you need to read, possibly determined at runtime, and `reader` is the stream to read from:

```
let mut buf = vec![0u8; bytes_to_read];
reader.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
```

The part that wasn't clear to me from the `read_exact` documentation was that the target buffer can be a dynamically-allocated `Vec`.

Thanks to the Rust Gitter community for pointing me to this solution.

Comment: It's also not clear what happens if EOF is returned before bytes_to_read.

Comment: That's specified in the documentation: "If this function encounters an "end of file" before completely filling the buffer, it returns an error of the kind `ErrorKind::UnexpectedEof`."

Comment: True, so I guess you can't actually do this. In the sense that it's not defined what happens to the buffer contents/impossible to recover.

Comment: How can you use a Vec as the target, when I attempt to do this with a `Vec::with_capacity(bytes_to_read)` the vec "length" is zero and nothing gets read

Comment: @Nanos Hopefully you've already figured this out elsewhere, but, the answer is you need to fill the `Vec` with some value first, (or unsafely set the length I guess). The `vec![0u8; bytes_to_read]` used above fills the `Vec` with `bytes_to_read` zeroes.

Comment: Same problem. `Vec::with_capacity` won't allocate until you append to it, so if you try to `read_exact` into it, it'll read 0 bytes. You can either call `vec.resize(bytes_to_read, 0);` or use the `vec!` macro - the macro is faster.

Answer (score 25):

It sounds like you want [`Read::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.take) and [`Read::read_to_end`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_end).

This will allow you to read data into a `&mut Vec<u8>`, which is useful when you want to reuse an existing buffer or don't have an appropriately sized slice already. This allows you to avoid initializing the data with dummy values before overwriting them with the newly-read information:

```
use std::{
    io::{prelude::*, BufReader},
    str,
};

fn read_n<R>(reader: R, bytes_to_read: u64) -> Vec<u8>
where
    R: Read,
{
    let mut buf = vec![];
    let mut chunk = reader.take(bytes_to_read);
    // Do appropriate error handling for your situation
    // Maybe it's OK if you didn't read enough bytes?
    let n = chunk.read_to_end(&mut buf).expect("Didn't read enough");
    assert_eq!(bytes_to_read as usize, n);
    buf
}

fn main() {
    let input_data = b"hello world";
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(&input_data[..]);

    let first = read_n(&mut reader, 5);
    let _ = read_n(&mut reader, 1);
    let second = read_n(&mut reader, 5);

    println!(
        "{:?}, {:?}",
        str::from_utf8(&first),
        str::from_utf8(&second)
    );
}
```

If you are worried that `Read::take` consumes the reader by reference, note that `take` comes from [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html) and [`Read` is implemented for any mutable reference to a type that implements `Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.51.0/std/io/trait.Read.html#impl-Read-13). You can also use [`Read::by_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.by_ref) to create this mutable reference.

See also:

- [Whats the idiomatic way to reference BufReader/BufWriter when passing it between functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39464237/155423)
- [Why does Iterator::take_while take ownership of the iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31374051/155423)

Comment: Thanks.. doesn't take() consume the reader?
My usecase is that i have a tcpstream (part of a struct) from which i read lines. Sometimes in between i don't need to read a line but a specific amount of bytes. Afterwards i'll need to read lines again...

Comment: It does, but "the reader" can be a `&mut R` i.e a temporary mutable reference to another reader. Take uses a by-value API so that all use cases are supported. This model appears in some different corners of rust.

Comment: @buster as bluss points out, `&mut R` also implements the `Read` trait. My example uses that to good effect - that's why I pass in `&mut reader` in the main method of the example.

Comment: @buster @Shepmaster how did you guys figure out that `Read::take` also accepts a `&mut reader`? Wondering how I would be able to figure that out myself next time. :)

Comment: @Kaeros [`take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.take) comes from [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html) and [`Read` is implemented for any mutable reference to a type that implements `Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.37.0/std/io/trait.Read.html#impl-Read-12). See also [Whats the idiomatic way reference BufReader/BufWriter when passing between functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39464237/155423);

Comment: Also `Read` has [`by_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.by_ref) which specifically creates a sub-reader by reference. So even without knowing that you can just create a mutable reference and that's also `Read`, you can always call `reader.by_ref()` and pass *that* in.

Comment: The `buf` should be created with `.with_capacity(bytes_to_read)`, to avoid memory allocations.

Comment: can you compare this answer to the `read_exact` answer above?

Comment: @EvanCarroll probably the biggest difference is that `read_exact` requires you to provide a buffer, while `read_to_end` will allocate one. Also, `take` returns another type that implements `Read` and can be further chained,