# Whats the idiomatic way to reference BufReader/BufWriter when passing it between functions?

Tags: io, rust

After reading the [`std::io::BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) docs, I'm not sure how to best pass a `BufReader` between functions. Multiple permutations are allowed, but which is best?

I have a function that takes a file:

```
use std::{fs::File, io::BufReader};

fn read_some_data(f: &mut std::fs::File) {
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(f);
    read_some_other_data(&mut reader);
}
```

While this can be made to work, which permutation of reference access should be used when passing the reader around to other functions?

- `&mut BufReader<&mut File>`
- `BufReader<&mut File>`
- `&mut BufReader<File>`
- `BufReader<File>`

Since there is no need for each function to own the data I was thinking it would be best to pass as `&mut BufReader<&mut File>`, but the example in the docs uses `<File>`.

Whats a good rule of thumb to use here?

While this example uses `BufReader`, I assume the same answer would apply to `BufWriter` too.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The most idiomatic way is probably not to reference `std::io::BufReader` at all. You actually want to refer to the traits `Read` and/or `BufRead`

```
use std::io:BufRead;

// Could also take by move if needed
fn read_data<R: BufRead>(r: &mut R);
```

The function usually doesn't really care whether a reader is specifically the type `std::io::BufReader`, merely that it has the same functionality.

This also gives you complete freedom to choose between `BufReader<File>`, `BufReader<&mut File>` or whichever other specialization you need. (It doesn't even have to be a file, which can help for testing!)

As for whether to use `&mut` versus a move, generally in Rust it's standard to only request what you need. If you (and the functions you call) only require an immutable reference (`&T`), use that, if you require mutability, use `&mut T`.

Move is a bit more flexible, because while it can be used simply based on whether you need to use a function that takes something by value, it's also frequently used to assert that the function will "use up" the data in some way.

This is why `BufReader` usually takes a `File` and not a reference, and why most high-level "parse this file" IO functions tend to move by value. It's generally not the case that you consume part of a `File` or reader with one adapter, and the rest with another.

In fact, this is conceptually so strong that rather than giving a reference, it's much more common to just move the `File` into a higher-level reader and call a function like `into_inner` to retrieve the file whenever you need to switch adapters.

Comment: I'm very new to rust, but wouldn't fn read_data<R: Read>(r: &mut R) be a better solution?

Comment: @PhilipRidout that entirely depends on whether you're using the `BufRead` methods. Ones like `split` or `lines` are really common.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the way `BufReader`'s methods are invoked (on `&mut self` or `self`) I would say you will usually want to pass `&mut BufReader`, or `BufReader` if the function needs to own the `BufReader` in order to e.g. convert it into a `Bytes` or `Chars` iterator.

The reason why docs describe `BufReader<File>` and not `BufReader<&mut File>` is because the [`BufReader` owns its underlying `Read` instance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/up/src/libstd/io/buffered.rs.html#49).

Comment: Hi, I'm learning Rust. The link is broken but I can't help fix it, because I don't understand the sentence "`BufReader` owns its underlying `Read` instance" ... [`BufReader` is a struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#), [`Read` is a trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html), right?. Wouldn't it be more accurate to say ["`BufReader` **implements** the `BufRead` trait"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#impl-BufRead-for-BufReader%3CR%3E)? Or maybe "`BufReader<R>` owns its underlying `R` instance"?